# Laravel SMTP 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

I use SMTP to send emails from Laravel 8. It works well in email Notifications but gets the error below while calling `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send`:

> 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

I can't find the difference of opening smtp socket between Notification and Mail::send.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same error by specifying the encryption on .env property MAIL_ENCRYPTION as tls. Confirm this is done before troubleshooting further if the error persists.